# Proper way to delete an image on a live server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I created a simple method that deletes an image from the server.

```
    public static void deleteImage(string deletePath)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(deletePath))
        {
            FileNotFoundException ex = new FileNotFoundException();
            throw ex;
        }

        try
        {
            File.Delete(deletePath);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

The method works great on the Visual Studio development server, but when I try it out on the live server that uses IIS I keep getting an error saying the resource is in use. It eventually works after about 10 attempts but I can't afford this.

Maybe I need to "lock" the file for this to work on IIS?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you catching exceptions, only to throw them? Plus it's better to do just a `throw;` instead of a `throw ex;`, that way you keep the original stack trace.

Comment: I always handle exceptions on the outer level (ie. the calling method). So the exception is thrown and caught in whatever method called it.

Comment: If you remove the try/catch, then still the exceptions get propagated to the upper level. Just a `catch(Exception ex) { throw ex; }` doesn't do anything useful, other than destroying the original stacktrace.

Comment: Yes I know, it's just something I like to do because of my OCD lol!

Comment: Do you have an idea what is creating the file or keeping it locked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
FileInfo myfileinf = new FileInfo(deletePath);
myfileinf.Delete();
```

Comment: Don't know what the difference is between File.Delete and this one but this one works great!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the file on the IIS is used by some other process in most cases. The simplest solution is to try to remove the file in a loop waiting for the other process to release the lock. Still, you should consider to set the maximum number of tries and to wait for couple of miliseconds between each try:

```
    public static void DeleteImage(string filePath, int maxTries = 0) // if maxTries is 0 we will try until success
    {
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            int tryNumber = 0;

            while (tryNumber++ < maxTries || maxTries == 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    File.Delete(filePath);
                    break;
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                    // file locked - we must try again

                    // you may want to sleep here for a while
                    // Thread.Sleep(10);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Incorporated this into my solution too.

Answer (score 0):

```
String filePath = string.Empty;
string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);    
filePath = Server.MapPath("../Images/gallery/") + filename;
System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
```

Comment: What exactly is the difference between yours and mine? And how did yo assume I was using a fileUpload control?

Comment: It is hard to say like this you may need to show the code you are using to upload the file. My Code simply deletes the file if found..